# First time mysqli, having INSERT error

Tags: php, mysql, insert, mysqli

I'm getting the following error from the following code. Connection works with no errors, all the input columns are correct, and I've dumbed down the inputs to just 0's to make sure it wasn't the variables I was passing. Any help would be greatly appreciated. MySQL ver 5.5.28.

> FAILURE You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'keys, values, childID, accessID) VALUES ('0','0','0','0')' at
>   line 1

```
$query="INSERT INTO carts (keys, values, childID, accessID)
                    VALUES
                    ('0','0','0','0')";
                    echo $query;
if (mysqli_query($link, $query) == FALSE) {echo "FAILURE " . mysqli_error($link);}
```

Been working 20 hours without sleep so if this a facepalm moment, I wont be surprised. I will say that I've never used mysqli, just mysql commands.

Comment: I should also mention that all my code is procedural, hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`keys` and `values` are a [reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) You can wrap it in backticks.

```
... (`keys`, `values`, ...
```

Comment: aaaaaaaaaaaand in retrospect, so is values. Thank you so much for knocking sense in to me. I can finally go to bed.